# Activate div function and backwards

Tags: javascript, jquery

First i want to open this solution from @kgd and then i want to close it backwards when i click on another div ... in this example the yellow div in the fiddle?

```js
var $a = $(".a"),
    $b = $(".b"),

function anim1() {
    $b.animate({width: 395}, {duration: 500, complete: anim2});
}

function anim2() {
    $a.animate({top:"0px"}, {duration: 500});
}

$(".b").click(function() {
    anim1();
});

var $a1 = $(".a"),
    $b1 = $(".b"),
    
function anim10() {
    $a1.animate({top:"-50px"}, {duration: 500});
}

function anim20() {
    $b1.animate({width: 137}, {duration: 500, complete: anim10});
}

$(".ab").click(function() {
    anim10();
});
```

```css
.example {
    width: 100%;
}

.a {
    width: 600px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #888;
    
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
}

.ab {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow; 
    float: left;
}

.b {
    width: 137px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: 50px;
    float: left;
}

.c {
    width: 395px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: 100px;
    
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example">
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="ab"></div>
        <div class="b"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And why my solution don't work?

Comment: @kgd Here is my Question :)

Comment: 1. Please include a link to "this solution from @kgd". 2. kgd won't receive a notification of your comment, because @username only works for users who have contributed to the topic (i.e. posted an answer or comment, or edited a question or answer). 3. In English the pronominal "I" should always be capitalized.

Comment: But...you haven't provided a link to the question you're referencing. There are currently 3 votes to close this question for the reason "unclear what you're asking". Two more and it gets closed. Providing context rather than just saying this is a solution from another question will probably prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code updated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UqgXc/31/). You were missing some commas where you were declaring the variables which was preventing the code from running.

```
var $a = $(".a"),
    $b = $(".b");

var $a1 = $(".a"),
    $b1 = $(".b");
```

**UPDATE**

I made a few small changes, but it really is difficult to determine what you are trying to accomplish based on the code and limited explanation. What I have provided is working code so maybe that will help get you going in the right direction?

Comment: Nice! But the problem is that the red div have the same width and not 137px... when i click on the yellow div

Comment: so backwards the div goes to top and then the red div must from 395px to 137px ... in his normal size